# Differences in texture painting between 2.7 and 2.8

Tags: texture-painting

Why when I'm texture painting it looks so bad, I mean in 2.7 the same texture look good but in 2.8 its look like that.

It should give the same color as skin behind but instead it give this black color.

Is this because of low quality of texture? Why does it looks good in 2.7 but not in 2.8?

[image]

Painting with stencil.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Switch color space from RAW back to SRGB. Try it out. Additionally: Texture stencils will paint with the original color marked white. If you're trying to create details using a stencil, consider painting in a "layer" for oppacity or roughness instead of the direct color.

Comment: I was trying all color spaces. With "layer" you mean that I shoud make new image for roughness and connect it to the principled BSDF? When im using stencil normaly in base color it looks the same (more black then color).